# Angular, exposing components in lazy-loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-router, lazy-loading

My app has *LazyModule*, that is lazy-loaded,
and also *RootModule*, which lazy-loads this.

When the app navigates to certain route, *LazyModule* will *lazily* render its component at `<router-outlet>` of *RootModule*`s component while the other `<router-outlet>`s will expose components by the `component` property in the route config.

root.component.html:

```
<!-- super-simplified version -->
<router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
...
<router-outlet name="side"></router-outlet>
...
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- primary -->
```

root.component.ts:

```
export class RootComponent {
  ...
  // called from somewhere...
  doNavigate() {
    this.route.navigate({outlets: {primary: 'hero', top: 'hero-header', side: 'hero-nav'}})
  }
  ...
}
```

root.routing.module.ts (route config):

```
  { path: 'hero', loadChildren: 'app/hero#LazyHeroModule' },
  { path: 'hero-header', component: HeroHeaderComponent, outlet: 'top' },
  { path: 'hero-nav', component: HeroNavComponent, outlet: 'side' }
  // components from 2nd, 3rd lines are declared in *RootModule*
```

The tricky part is that those route-config-components are **semantically related** to *LazyModule*. (They are all hero-related).

It seems ugly to me that `HeroHeaderComponent` and `HeroNavComponent` are not part of `LazyHeroModule`, but part of `RootModule`. (Am I right??)

I have more lazy-loaded modules that behave similar to *LazyModule*: Each one of those has corresponding *apart-from-family components* declared in *RootModule*:

```
  // config continues...
  { path: 'villain', loadChildren: 'app/villain#LazyVillainModule' },
  { path: 'villain-header', component: VillainHeaderComponent, outlet: 'top' },
  { path: 'villain-nav', component: VillainNavComponent, outlet: 'side' }
  // components from 2nd, 3rd lines are declared in *RootModule*
```

If these kind of route configs exists more, I think it is proper to leave `root.component.html` hosting data from different genres. (hero- or villain-related).

To make it clear, the root of the situation, I think, is that:

1. I don't want to touch the structure of `RootComponent`, e.g. the way it hosts header, side and content.
2. All genres have their own set of interfaces, e.g. Hero genre has hero-header, hero-side hero-content, ... etc, and Villain genre also has corresponding ones.

   - One genre's internal structure of interface A is different from another genre's one.
3. Some interface(component) of genres involves lazy-loaded module.(for some reason) But I want the other interfaces not requiring lazy-loaded module to be loaded on bootstrap like other components in eager-loaded module.

---

**Here is the question:**

Is it possible that lazy-load module bundle up those components which have semantic relationship to itself?

Whether it is or not, **Am I approaching the given problem correctly?**

---

The more concretely I write this question, the more I get confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same feeling you do, that something is wrong with the current architecture. I would put all of the hero stuff in the Hero module. So if HeroModule is lazy loaded, all that stuff (HeroHeader and HeroNav) will be lazy-loaded too.

So I would have a single outlet in RootComponent, and in each of the modules that get loaded within it, I would have the top and side as well as the primary children outlets.

Comment: Reviewing the question now, it's really my unreasonable obsession to the route config structure. Putting all related parts into one module is truly a reasonable and conventional approach.